# Unable to import package after installing with Anaconda

Tags: python, redis, anaconda, macos-catalina

I have installed Redis using Anaconda on MaxOSX Catalina

```
(base) ➜  ~ conda list  | grep redis
redis                     5.0.3                h1de35cc_0
```

```
(base) ➜  ~ which python
/Users/me/anaconda3/bin/python
```

```
(base) ➜  ~ python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 16:54:48)
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import redis
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'redis'
>>>
```

After searching across the web, and trying a couple of things, among them changing the sequence in my `$PATH` variable, I am still unable to get python to recognize the package.

Just for completeness, my `PATH` variable looks like this:

```
PATH=/Users/me/Library/Python/3.7/bin:/usr/local/smlnj/bin:/Users/me/anaconda3/bin:/Users/me/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Apple/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Users/me/Development/gocode/bin
```

Comment: I think you got the wrong package: `redis` is the database, `redis-py` is the python client. `conda install redis-py` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python package that provides interface for Redis is distinct from the `redis` package. Instead you need

```
conda install redis-py
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing redis using

```
conda install redis
```

Then I tried to use the redis package using `import redis` and I could replicate the same error you got.

**FIX :**

Try installing redis in the anaconda terminal using

```
pip install redis
```

and then tried

```
import redis
```

This works fine

Comment: Thank you, While this is comforting, and makes me feel less like a complete idiot. it does seem like something is broken in Conda :(

Comment: @MartinKristiansen Yes, I am not sure of the problem(maybe mac issues) but this is a usual problem with the anaconda(I have faced the same couple of times).

Comment: The underlying problem is not a problem with anaconda - so switching to pip is not really the answer, I'd say

Comment: @cel Like I said m not sure of the problem. But this worked for me so posted it.!!